# No suitable constructor error in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

So previously I failed to have a suitable constructor, because of naming violation. This time the naming is identical, yet it still fails.

I get the following error code:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Customer'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'Address' in 'Customer(string firstName, string lastName, Address Address, string email)'.'

With the following execution:

```
using (var db = new EshopContext())
{
    var test = db.Products
        .Where(p => p.Title == customSearchTag)
        .ToList(); //Error here

    foreach (var item in test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " for " + item.Price);
    }
}
```

Address.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Street { get; set; }
public string Zipcode { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }

public Address(string street, string zipcode, string city, string country)
{
    Street = street;
    Zipcode = zipcode;
    City = city;
    Country = country;
}
```

Customer.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public Address Address { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }

public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, Address Address, string email)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    this.Address = Address;
    Email = email;
}
```

I hope someone can tell my why this error happens. Because I don't know why it won't bind the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an empty constructor to avoid that error.

```cs
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, Address Address, string email)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        this.Address = Address;
        Email = email;
    }
    
    // Add this
    public Customer() {}
}
```

Comment: Damn, would never have thought that would fix those issues. But the errors keep happening. This time "An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details." - "SqlException: Invalid object name 'Products'."

Comment: @BaconBotMK1 Do you still get the same error as the one you posted in the question?

Comment: No, i get the error that "products" is an invalid object name

Comment: @BaconBotMK1 You can accept the answer if it got rid of your error which you posted in the question. And then ask separately for this other error.

Comment: @BaconBotMK1 Thank you. The `invalid object name` could be because you are having an issue with connecting to database, check if your connectionstring is correct

Comment: No worries, just forgot all about accepting it When migrating initially, it succeeded with the current string - Edit: So adding a new migration and updating the db fixed the issue! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BaconBotMK1 Yes I sometimes also forget to create new migration when modifying entities. Glad to hear it is working now.